# What is a small and fast real time compression technique, like lz77?

Tags: algorithm, compression

What is the minimum source length (in bytes) for LZ77? Can anyone suggest a small and fast real time compression technique (preferable with c source). I need it to store compressed text and fast retrieval for excerpt generation in my search engine.

---

thanks for all the response, im using D language for this project so it's kinda hard to port LZO to D codes. so im going with either LZ77 or Predictor. thanks again :)

Comment: https://catchchallenger.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_(compression_algorithm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I long ago had need for a simple, fast compression algorithm, and found Predictor.

While it may not be the best in terms of compression ratio, Predictor is certainly fast (very fast), easy to implement, and has a good worst-case performance.  You also don't need a license to implement it, which is goodness.

You can find a description *and* C source for Predictor in [Internet RFC 1978:  PPP Predictor Compression Protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1978.txt).

Comment: thanks, really simple algorithm. im trying it. quick question, is there a limit to source length?

Comment: I don't *think* so.  It's been a good ten years since I used it, and I doubt we had to compress anything huge (>2GB) back then :-)

Answer (score 4):

The [lzo compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel-Ziv-Oberhumer) is noted for its smallness and high speed, making it suitable for real-time use.  Decompression, which uses almost zero memory, is extremely fast and **can even exceed memory-to-memory copy** on modern CPUs due to the reduced number of memory reads.  [lzop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lzop) is an open-source implementation; versions for several other languages are available.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something more well known this is about the best compressor in terms of general compression you'll get.  LZMA, the 7-zip encoder.  http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

There's also LZJB:
https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/os/compress.c

It's pretty simple, based on LZRW1, and is used as the basic compression algorithm for ZFS.